# iOS14 - CMMotionActivityManager startActivityUpdatesToQueue not working

Tags: detect, ios14, motion

On iOS 14 I call 'startActivityUpdatesToQueue withHandler' from CMMotionActivityManager and my handler block (with CMMotionActivity parameter) is not called at all.

On iOS 12 the same code work correctly.

CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable is true
and 
CMMotionActivityManager authorizationStatus is CMAuthorizationStatusAuthorized.
In Info.plist I have added NSMotionUsageDescription key with description text.

What could be reason, how to fix it?

Thanks.